# Difficulty calling an api via Office Script

Tags: typescript, office-scripts

I'm trying to call a Salesforce Marketing Cloud API via Office Script (TS) and I get an error on the watch. I know I have to authenticate, but even after posting the token the error persists.

```
async function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
    // Retrieve sample JSON data from a test server.
    let fetchResult = await fetch('https://**********.auth.marketingcloudapis.com/v2/token');

    // Display the content in a readable format.
    console.log(fetchResult.status);
}
```

Line 3: Failed to fetch

I tried via google collab in Python and managed to make the connection without any problems

Comment: My tip, don’t do it. Call the API via PowerAutomate and do what you need from there.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Anyway I would like to call the API via Excel so I can share the file in read mode. The idea is not to turn it into a dashboard, but only for operational queries.